# combining two jquery functions for use on the same html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I combine these two jQuery functions ? or the .js . Trying to put them together in the same page makes the latter not work at all.

They work just fine for their job if I only use one on the page, but I need them both.

The first one I have is:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Dropdown Menu
        if (!($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == 6))) {
            $("ul#topnav li:has(ul)").addClass("dropdown");
        }
        $("ul#topnav li.dropdown").hover(function () {
            $('ul:first', this).css({
                visibility: "visible",
                display: "none"
            }).slideDown('normal');
        }, function () {
            $('ul:first', this).css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
        });
        $("div.prod_hold").hover(function () {
            $('.info', this).css({
                visibility: "visible",
                display: "none"
            }).slideDown('normal');
        }, function () {
            $('.info', this).css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
        });
        $("li.cat_hold").hover(function () {
            $('.info', this).fadeIn(300);
        }, function () {
            $('.info', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $("li.side_cart").hover(function () {
            $('#cart', this).fadeIn(500);
        }, function () {
            $('#cart', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $("li.side_currency").hover(function () {
            $('#currency', this).fadeIn(500);
        }, function () {
            $('#currency', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $("li.side_lang").hover(function () {
            $('#language', this).fadeIn(500);
        }, function () {
            $('#language', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $("li.side_search").hover(function () {
            $('#search', this).fadeIn(500);
        }, function () {
            $('#search', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $(".main_menu li").hover(function () {
            $('.secondary', this).fadeIn(500);
        }, function () {
            $('.secondary', this).fadeOut(200);
        });
        $(".cat_right ul li a").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                paddingLeft: 20,
                color: '#ccc'
            }, "fast")
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                paddingLeft: 10,
                color: '#999'
            }, "fast")
        });

        // Tipsy - tooltips jQuery plugin
        $('a.wish_button, a.compare_button, a#button-cart, a.twitter_follow').tipsy({
            gravity: 's',
            fade: true,
            title: function () {
                return this.getAttribute('original-title').toUpperCase();
            }
        });
        $('#service_links li a').tipsy({
            gravity: 'e',
            fade: true,
            title: function () {
                return this.getAttribute('original-title').toUpperCase();
            }
        });

        // SLIDING ELEMENTS
        $("ul.categories li, #sidebar ul.secondary_menu li").hover(function () {
            $("a", this).stop().animate({
                left: "15px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 200
            });
        }, function () {
            $("a", this).stop().animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 200
            });
        });

        // FADING ELEMENTS
        $(".logo img, .oferta_s, .oferta_d").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.6
            }, "medium")
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, "medium")
        });
        $(".intro").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                paddingBottom: 230
            }, "medium")
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                paddingBottom: 140
            }, "slow")
        });
        $(".desc_box,.desc_box2").hover(function () {
            $(".desc_box,.desc_box2").not(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.7
            }, "fast")
        }, function () {
            $(".desc_box,.desc_box2").not(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, "fast")
        });
    });
})(window.jQuery);

// non jQuery scripts below
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;
    $('ul#myRoundabout').roundabout({
        'btnNext': '.next_round',
        'btnPrev': '.previous_round'
    }).hover(

    function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function () {
        interval = startAutoPlay();
    });
    interval = startAutoPlay();
});

function startAutoPlay() {
    return setInterval(function () {
        $('ul#myRoundabout').roundabout_animateToPreviousChild();
    }, 6000);
}
```

When I add this second code the problems start.. and the code is :

```
<!-- Validate email using regular expression -->

function validateEmail(emailValue) {
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/;
    return emailPattern.test(emailValue);
}
<!-- Validate Form fields -->

function validateForm() {
    var send_message = true;
    if (jQuery("textarea#message").val().length < 2) {
        jQuery("label#message_error").slideDown();
        jQuery("textarea#message").focus();
        send_message = false;
    }
    if (!validateEmail(jQuery("input#email").val())) {
        jQuery("label#email_error").slideDown();
        jQuery("input#email").focus();
        send_message = false;
    }
    if (jQuery("input#name").val().length < 2) {
        jQuery("label#name_error").slideDown();
        jQuery("input#name").focus();
        send_message = false;
    }
    return send_message;
}
jQuery(function () {
    <!-- Contact Form validation -->
    jQuery('.error').hide();
    jQuery("input#name").bind("keyup focusout", function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length > 1) {
            jQuery("label#name_error").slideUp();
        } else {
            jQuery("label#name_error").slideDown();
        }
    });
    jQuery("input#email").bind("keyup focusout", function () {
        if (validateEmail(jQuery(this).val())) {
            jQuery("label#email_error").slideUp();
        } else {
            jQuery("label#email_error").slideDown();
        }
    });
    jQuery("textarea#message").bind("keyup focusout", function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length > 1) {
            jQuery("label#message_error").slideUp();
        } else {
            jQuery("label#message_error").slideDown();
        }
    });
    <!-- Submitting Contact Form -->
    jQuery("form#contact_form").submit(function () {
        var dataString = jQuery(this).serialize();
        if (validateForm()) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FormToEmail.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    jQuery('#contact_form').slideUp('slow', function () {
                        jQuery(this).html("<div id='confirmation'></div>");
                        jQuery('#confirmation').html("<h4>Mesajul a fost trimis cu succes!</h4>").append("<p>Va multumim pentru ca ne-ati contactat. Va vom raspunde la e-mail in cel mai scurt timp posibil!</p>");
                        Cufon.refresh();
                        jQuery(this).slideDown('slow');
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: How does the second one not work?  Doesn't run? Throwing an error?

Comment: Please check the javascript console to see what the error is

Comment: @ Abe: The second one works just fine. Alone, without the first .js . But when put together , the second of these two fails to work.

Comment: You shouldn't be using html comments (`<!-- comment -->`) within JavaScript.  Use JavaScript comments (`// comment` or `/* comment */`) instead.

Comment: Don't be shy tell us what does't work, do you get a js error?

Comment: Also, you don't need that self-invoking anonymous function around your first `.ready()` call.  You can just set `$` as the first parameter in your ready handler: `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { ... });`.  Or better yet: `jQuery(function ($) { ... });`.

Comment: @ gilly : Sorry for the delay, I have been trying to see what was not working. It was the comments bugging it out. silly me. I changed them all to /* comm */ and it works just fine.

Comment: @ TJB and Ibu : I got the error that jQuery(function () { .. } ( the one with the submission of the form ) is not a function :-s , it was the comments

Comment: This is odd, you had a valid question and got a valid answer, but it really had nothing to do with jQuery. I'm going to edit your question to generalize the problem so that it's useful to others.

Comment: read the [faq] and then add the correct answer *as an answer*.

Comment: @dlamblin I already edited it saying what the problem was, and how i fixed it. If you have anything to add, or to change to make it helpful to others please do it.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Oh, I see now. Thank you. I'm new around here, and first question asked :-s

Comment: I suppose no one said it earlier, welcome to [SO]. Take some time to play with the editors and [learn how to use markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @dlamblin, Don't add the answer to the question. Add it as an ***answer***.

Comment: @zzzzBov That's not all I did. I also shortened the JavaScript and generalized the title/question. I felt that the *answer* was not mine to contribute. And when I looked at the page, Christian had already updated it. It would be valid if the answer was both an answer and an update to the question.

Comment: I will answer the question now. Couldn't do it earlier because it told me that users with less than 80 reputation can't answer their own question in 8h from the time it was posted. Or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

*** EDIT ***
The problem has been fixed, it was the comments.
 Changed the `<!-- comm -->` into `/* comm */` and it works just fine. 
Thank you all for your time and help!